# Identifying the first occurrence of a state change in the TfsWarehouse DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, tfs, sql-server-2012, azure-pipelines

Hi seeking assistance with the following, I'm working on a report that will allow me to distinguish when a bug failure occurs during the lifecycle of a bug. Our current process has bugs going through the following states:

> New > Committed > In Progress > Build > Resolved > Done

And if a failure occurs the bug would go from Resolved to:

> Failed > In Progress > Build > Resolved > Done

It could also fail again. The `TfsWarehouse` records these changes as a revision. The issue I'm having is any change made to the bug also counts as a revision - this could be a change to another field such as the title, description, etc. Every revision creates a record in the table, so there are instances of multiple records with the same `PreviousState` and `System_State` entries. I was able to write a query to distinguish the first instance of a state change and eliminate the duplicate see below:

```
WITH myTable (WorkItem, PreviousState, ChangedDate, ChangedBy, ID, Title, CurrentState, RevisionNo, Reason, CreatedDate, toNew, toCommited, toIP, toBuild, toResolved, toDone, toFailed, FailedtoIP)

AS (
SELECT
      [WorkItem]
      ,[PreviousState]
      ,[System_ChangedDate]
      ,dp.Name as 'Changed By'
      ,[System_Id]
      ,[System_Title]
      ,[System_State]
      ,[System_Rev]
      ,[System_Reason]
      ,[System_CreatedDate]
    ,row_number() over (partition by System_Id 
                                order by (case when PreviousState IS NULL AND System_State = 'New' then 1 else 2 end), System_ChangedDate asc) as newseq
    ,row_number() over (partition by System_Id
                                order by (case when PreviousState = 'New' AND System_State = 'Committed' then 1 else 2 end), System_ChangedDate asc) as ntocomseq
    ,row_number() over (partition by System_Id
                                order by (case when PreviousState = 'Committed' AND System_State = 'In Progress' then 1 else 2 end), System_ChangedDate asc) as ctoipseq
    ,row_number() over (partition by System_Id
                                order by (case when PreviousState = 'In Progress' AND System_State = 'Build' then 1 else 2 end), System_ChangedDate asc) as iptobseq
    ,row_number() over (partition by System_Id
                                order by (case when PreviousState = 'Build' AND System_State = 'Resolved' then 1 else 2 end), System_ChangedDate asc) as btoresseq
    ,row_number() over (partition by System_Id
                                order by (case when PreviousState = 'Resolved' AND System_State = 'Done' then 1 else 2 end), System_ChangedDate asc) as restodseq
    ,row_number() over (partition by System_Id
                                order by (case when PreviousState = 'Resolved' AND System_State = 'Failed' then 1 else 2 end), System_ChangedDate asc) as restofseq
    ,row_number() over (partition by System_Id
                                order by (case when PreviousState = 'Failed' AND System_State = 'In Progress' then 1 else 2 end), System_ChangedDate asc) as ftoipseq
FROM [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[vDimWorkItemOverlay] as dwi1
    LEFT JOIN [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[DimPerson] AS dp  
    ON dwi1.System_ChangedBy__PersonSK = dp.PersonSK

  WHERE System_Id IN (36708

        --SELECT DISTINCT System_Id

        --FROM 
        --  [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[vDimWorkItemOverlay] AS dwi2

        --WHERE System_State IN ('Failed')
        --AND IterationLevel0 = 'v7'
        --AND YEAR(System_CreatedDate) = 2017 
        )

  )

  SELECT *

  FROM myTable
  Where toNew = 1 or toCommited = 1 or toIP = 1 or toBuild = 1 or toResolved = 1 or toDone = 1 or toFailed = 1 or FailedtoIP = 1
  Order by ID, RevisionNo
```

What the above does is uses a CTE and basically adds a 1 to the first instance of any state change. It uses the `row_number() over(partition)` function to do so. When the first instance of 'Previous State = New and System_State = Committed' is encountered then the column `ntocomseq` will have a 1 (sort of like a flag) Here are my results:

[image]

The sub query in there is commented out but all that does is further filter the list of possible work items to those that were only ever failed.

The issue I'm having is when an item fails again and is fixed, the query is not catching it. I.e if `PreviousState=InProgress` and `System_State=Build` a second time it will not be given a 1, it actually gets a 2 in some instances.  Is there another way to fix this? Has anyone else using the `TfsWarehouse` db tables encountered a similar issue?

What I would like to get is the above result but with the instances of a the bug going from `In Progress` to `Build` the second time. There could be an issue with my partition, as I'm partitioning the entire work item ID, so it's only looking for the first instance of the state change but just once. I need the first instance of a change every time.

Let me know if you have any questions or need further explanation thank you! Hopefully it's not too confusing.

Here is an example of the sample data - I just selected the columns that I am using in the CTE

```
WorkItem PreviousState  System_ChangedDate  System_Id   System_Title    System_State    System_Rev  System_Reason   System_CreatedDate

<!-- -->

Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor NULL           2017-07-19 15:40:12.873  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   New 1       New defect reported                     2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor New            2017-07-20 07:32:26.800  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Committed   2       Commitment made by the team 2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Committed      2017-07-20 07:32:28.907  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   In Progress 3       Work started                2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor In Progress    2017-07-20 07:32:31.660  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Build       4       Build pending                   2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Build          2017-07-20 07:32:34.410  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Resolved    5       Fixed                       2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Build          2017-07-20 07:33:55.623  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Resolved    6       Fixed                       2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Build          2017-07-20 12:09:26.707  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Resolved    7       Fixed                       2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Resolved       2017-07-20 12:09:54.177  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Failed      8       Bug not fixed                   2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Resolved       2017-07-20 12:10:17.037  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Failed      9   Bug not fixed                   2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Resolved       2017-07-20 12:12:53.960  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Failed      10      Bug not fixed                   2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Failed         2017-07-21 07:26:40.930  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   In Progress 11   Work started               2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Failed         2017-07-24 07:36:44.370  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   In Progress 12      Work started                2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor In Progress    2017-07-24 10:16:37.360  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Build       13      Build pending                   2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor In Progress    2017-07-24 10:16:45.373  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Build       14      Build pending                   2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Build          2017-07-24 10:16:57.720  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Resolved    15      Fixed                       2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Build          2017-07-24 10:17:38.133  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Resolved    16      Fixed                       2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Resolved       2017-07-24 10:17:44.010  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Done 17 Resolution accepted     2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Resolved       2017-07-25 15:25:36.490  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Done 18     Resolution accepted                     2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Resolved       2017-08-11 13:54:08.960  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Done 19     Resolution accepted                     2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Resolved       2017-10-10 15:09:32.593  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Done 20     Resolution accepted                     2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Resolved       2017-10-10 15:33:41.343  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Done 21     Resolution accepted                     2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor Resolved       2017-10-10 15:35:01.910  36708   MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor   Done 22     Resolution accepted                     2017-07-19 15:40:12.873
```

Comment: if you could give a small sample data, for a single work item perhaps, this would make it easier to solve. Your results of the cte don't help much because can't see what the original data looks like. The explanation was great, but the sample data and expected output would be critical for a MCVE.

Comment: Thanks for the response and good point. I went ahead and added a capture of the sample data. This is the same work item as depicted in my original example.

Comment: Cool @dougie88. Can you paste that as text so that we can copy it into test environments? Images aren't too friendly lol.

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I'm following you. let me know if this get's you where you want to be. Since you are on 2012, we can use `LEAD` and `LAG`. In the snippet below, I'm g creating two extra columns. What they do is flag when the row has changed based off the previous row, or the next row. So, essentially "deduplicating" your data in a sense. Run this as is first and focus on the CurrentState column, and the two columns I added. Then, you can use the appropriate where clause that I have commented out to limit them to the rows you want.

```
declare @table table(
                        WorkItem varchar(4000)
                        ,PreviousState varchar(256) null
                        ,ChangedDate datetime2
                        ,ID int
                        ,Title varchar(4000)
                        ,CurrentState varchar(256)
                        ,RevisionNo int
                        ,Reason varchar(256)
                        ,CreatedDate datetime2)
insert into @table
values
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor',NULL,'2017-07-19 15:40:12.873',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','New',1,'New defect reported','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','New','2017-07-20 07:32:26.800',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Committed',2,'Commitment made by the team','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Committed','2017-07-20 07:32:28.907',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','In Progress',3,'Work started','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','In Progress','2017-07-20 07:32:31.660',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Build',4,'Build pending','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Build','2017-07-20 07:32:34.410',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Resolved',5,'Fixed','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Build','2017-07-20 07:33:55.623',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Resolved',6,'Fixed','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Build','2017-07-20 12:09:26.707',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Resolved',7,'Fixed','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Resolved','2017-07-20 12:09:54.177',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Failed',8,'Bug not fixed','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Resolved','2017-07-20 12:10:17.037',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Failed',9,'Bug not fixed','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Resolved','2017-07-20 12:12:53.960',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Failed',10,'Bug not fixed','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Failed','2017-07-21 07:26:40.930',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','In Progress',11,'Work started','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Failed','2017-07-24 07:36:44.370',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','In Progress',12,'Work started','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','In Progress','2017-07-24 10:16:37.360',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Build',13,'Build pending','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','In Progress','2017-07-24 10:16:45.373',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Build',14,'Build pending','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Build','2017-07-24 10:16:57.720',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Resolved',15,'Fixed','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Build','2017-07-24 10:17:38.133',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Resolved',16,'Fixed','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Resolved','2017-07-24 10:17:44.010',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Done',17,'Resolution accepted','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Resolved','2017-07-25 15:25:36.490',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Done',18,'Resolution accepted','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Resolved','2017-08-11 13:54:08.960',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Done',19,'Resolution accepted','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Resolved','2017-10-10 15:09:32.593',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Done',20,'Resolution accepted','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Resolved','2017-10-10 15:33:41.343',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Done',21,'Resolution accepted','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873'),
('Bug 36708 MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Resolved','2017-10-10 15:35:01.910',36708,'MEP Reno: Can edit stylegroup of child platform views and form dimensions of grandchild platform views in detailed editor','Done',22,'Resolution accepted','2017-07-19 15:40:12.873')


;with cte as(
select
    *
    ,RevisionNumber = row_number() over (partition by ID order by ChangedDate)
    ,FirstInstance = case when lag(CurrentState) over (partition by ID order by ChangedDate) = CurrentState then 0 else 1 end
    ,LastInstance = case when lead(CurrentState) over (partition by ID order by ChangedDate) = CurrentState then 0 else 1 end
from @table)

select
    *
from cte
order by ID, ChangedDate
--where FirstInstance = 1
--where LastInstance = 1
```

Comment: Wow, that works! Very good work, I appreciate your help! What I can do now is change those original case statements and set them as additional flags for each individual state change - i.e for Resolved to Failed it would be the char F or something of that nature. Thanks a lot!